# How to show value of ArrayList in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I am using jasper report 5.
I am able to print simple variable values, but i am not getting how to print values of ArrayList variable.

I have included

```
<field name="billNo" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="paymentType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="subTotal" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="vat" class="java.lang.Float"/>
    <field name="total" class="java.lang.Float"/>
```

I am printing above fields like

```
 <textField>
        <reportElement x="276" y="70" width="180" height="15"/>
    <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

same for others.That is working fine.

Now I have an ArrayList `customerList`.
which have fields `customerName`,`address` etc.

I want to show these values using jasper report how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass ArrayList to JasperReports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624562/how-to-pass-arraylist-to-jasperreports)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12209300/876298)

Answer (score 0):

Create another subreport for Customer List like :

```
<subreport>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0"></reportElement>
<subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR"><subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{customerList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "CustomerList.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

In the new sub report

```
<textField>
        <reportElement x="276" y="70" width="180" height="15"/>
    <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerName}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

Comment: I changed `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` to path `$P{E:/Project/cxn/cnx/web/pages/billing/}`. Then it is showing following error `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. Parameter not found : E:/Project/cxn/cnx/web/pages/billing/
  2. Parameter not found : E:/Project/cxn/cnx/web/pages/billing/`

Comment: In `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` **SUBREPORT_DIR** is a parameter sent to .jrxml file from java. Use this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_parameters.htm) to know how to use parameters.